# Maxima: draw a set of 3d points

Tags: math, draw, maxima

I've been trying to draw a list of points in a 3D cartesian system with no avail.

I played around with `plot3d`, `draw3d`, `wxdraw3d`, and reading the doc gave me the impression `draw3d` should be the right choice.

However, a first attempt failed with error

```
3D graphic object not recognized
```

[image]

which I thought might be because the list consisted of vectors (coming from a previous matrix operation), so I've tried converting each single element into a sub-list

[image]

with `list_matrix_entries`, still to receive the same error.

What am I missing here? What is the right way to draw a three-dimensional cartesian system and a set of points into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a variable name `points` that is a name of function.

```
load(draw);
pts:[[1,1,1],[1,2,2],[1,3,2],[1,4,3]];
scene:points(pts);
draw3d(scene);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That, and then I had to restart Maxima because it kept giving out the same error, although I re-evaluated all steps in that document. After restart and no changes, just another re-eval, the graph worked!

Comment: For not having to restart Maxima, add at beginning `kill(all)`.

Comment: @draconigen If you like an answer you can upvote it, even if you have already accepted it.

Comment: @miracle173 Of course, I did, but as I'm new around here, Stack Overflow says: "_Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score._"